# Trying to apply a gradient on my ng2-charts chart : createLinearGradient is not a function

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I'm trying to apply a linear gradient on my canvas chart with ng2-charts 
I'm getting this error :

```
DashboardComponent.html:278 ERROR TypeError: this.canvas.createLinearGradient 
is not a function
```

My component :

```
@ViewChildren('chart') canvas: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.getUserXps(this.id);
 let gradient = this.canvas.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 0);
 console.log(this.canvas);
 gradient.addColorStop(0, 'green');
 gradient.addColorStop(1, 'blue');
 this.lineChartColor[0].backgroundColor = gradient;
}
```

My html :

```
<canvas #chart baseChart height=500 width=1024  [datasets]="lineChartData" 
[labels]="lineChartLabels" [colors]="lineChartColor"
[legend]="lineChartLegend" [chartType]="lineChartType" 
[options]="lineChartOptions" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Hey! Could you please tell me how did you manage to do it in the end?

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare your canvas as an `ElementRef` type, not `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. Check the solution Charlie-Hua provides in https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/599, that worked for me.
Your code should look something like:

```
@ViewChild('chart') canvas: ElementRef;

ngOnInit {
    const gradient = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'blue');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'white');
    this.chartColors = [
        {
            backgroundColor: gradient
        }
    ];
}
```

And you template:

```
<canvas #canvasChart baseChart [colors]="chartColors" ......>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Hi! where did you declare "chartColor"  as like in you code it's not working?